# Appending Struct to File

Tags: c, file, struct

I am working on a project where I need to save structure in binary file. I want to append the structure to the file without overwriting it. It works for one record but when I add the second record and try to read the file I get segmentation fault error.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
   struct index {
      char* conflict;
      char* resolution;
   };

   struct index *new_conflict = malloc(sizeof(struct index));
   new_conflict->conflict = "conflict";
   new_conflict->resolution = "resolution";

   FILE *conflict_index = fopen("conflict_index", "ab+");

   if (conflict_index) {
      fwrite(&new_conflict, sizeof(struct index), 1, conflict_index);
      fwrite(&new_conflict, sizeof(struct index), 1, conflict_index);
      fclose(conflict_index);
   }

   conflict_index = fopen("conflict_index", "rb");
   if (conflict_index) {
     while(1) {
        struct index *object2 = malloc(sizeof(struct index));
        if (!fread(&object2, sizeof(struct index), 1, conflict_index))
            break;
        printf("write_conflict_index: CONFLICT %s", object2->conflict);
        printf("write_conflict_index: RESOLUTION %s", object2->resolution);
     }
     fclose(conflict_index);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Can anybody help please.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
   struct index {
      char* conflict;
      char* resolution;
   };
```

These are pointers to characters. If you write them, that is fine, but if you read them, then there is no memory allocated for them, causing the segmentation fault.

A better way is to make them fixed sized strings so they can be written and read back, for example:

```
   struct index {
      char conflict[50];
      char resolution[50];
   };
```

(Note also that you don't write the strings, but just the pointer value. And when reading back, you allocate the object again and again without storing it somewhere, so you leak memory.)

Comment: How can i fixed the code using char* ? i don't know the exact size of strings it could be very long o very short. This is just an example there is no problem for leak memory.

Comment: If you want to write and read fixed-sized records, you must make the fields the longest you want to accept and truncate any longer inputs.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned by Paul the pointer has to changed to array. i.e.

```
   struct index {
      char* conflict;
      char* resolution;
   };
```

To

```
   struct index {
      char conflict[100];
      char resolution[100];
   };
```

The array size can be given after analysing the maximum character the array should hold.

**In addition, I want to point out the code for fwrite and fread used is not correct.**

```
size_t fwrite ( const void * ptr, size_t size, size_t count, FILE * stream );
size_t fread ( void * ptr, size_t size, size_t count, FILE * stream );
```

**fwrite and fread function require pointer, but the passed argument is pointer to the pointer.** In the code fwrite and fread are

```
fwrite(&new_conflict, sizeof(struct index), 1, conflict_index);
fread(&object2, sizeof(struct index), 1, conflict_index)
```

**new_conflict and object2 is already a pointer to struct index**. So the code should be like below

```
fwrite(new_conflict, sizeof(struct index), 1, conflict_index);
fread(object2, sizeof(struct index), 1, conflict_index)
```